# How to use Watir to find a specific link when all the links have the same display text?

Tags: watir, webrat

The links are wrapped in a span:

```
<span class='editbio'>
<a href="/experts/3987/edit">Edit</a>
</span>
...
<span class='addbio'>
<a href="/experts/3987/edit">Edit</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
browser.span(:class, "editbio").link(:text, "Edit")
```

to get the first link
vs

```
browser.span(:class, "addbio").link(:text, "Edit")
```

for the second link?

You can get a list of elements and tags you can use at [Watir: Methods supported by Element](http://pettichord.com/watirtutorial/docs/watir_cheat_sheet/WTR/Methods%20supported%20by%20Element.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you happen to know how to do it with webrat, too?

Comment: ask the webrat folks.  I added their tag so hopefully they will notice

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use multiple arguments with the Watir's link method:
http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Multiple+Attributes

For your example, the accepted answer works fine. But if both of your links were in a single span and had the same display text, like so:

```
<span class='edit'>
  <a href="/experts/3987/edit">Edit</a>
  <a href="/experts/3986/edit">Edit</a>
</span>
```

You could use something like this for the **second** link (zero-based index):

```
browser.span(:class, 'edit').link(text: 'Edit', index: 1)
```